# Why are my bathroom light and fan wired to the same switch?

Tags: wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan

In my apartment my bathroom light and fan comes on at the same time. Is that standard for an apartment?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: That's very common, at least in the Americas.  It's also the cheapest and easiest way, as a lot of (older) buildins don't have wiring for separate circuits for a fan and light.

Comment: I joined this site just to upvote this question.  I've wondered for a long time why people do this.

Answer (score 9):

Many apartment owners wire the fan and light to a single switch. The reason I have done it is to limit moisture build up. Not all renters are responsible enough to turn on the fan while using the shower. Failing to do so can cause moisture to build up and allow mold to form.

Comment: Yes, but along those lines, the fan usually needs to run for many minutes after the room is unoccupied to remove moisture.  But it can't because the light was switched off when the resident left.  This is why draconian states, like California, now require either automatic, or always-on, fans.

Comment: @BrockAdams There exist fans which you connect four wires to: ground, neutral, phase for power, phase from light. Such a fan will turn on when the light is turned on and keep running for a certain number of minutes after the light is turned off.

Comment: Most hotels have something similar, which means you either freeze in the shower or shower in the dark.